# Wordpress customizer change sanitize_callback for setting doesn't have any effect

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem:
I have replaced the color input in the customizer with an input that supports the alpha channel. The sanitization function from Wordpress is only for hex colors but I get rgba() colors. I wrote a sanitization function that works perfectly for any new control I add to the customizer but if I replace an existing one and change the sanitize_callback parameter of the corresponding setting to my own function (`$wp_customize->get_setting("background_color")->sanitize_callback = "slug_sanitize_color";`) Wordpress still uses its standard sanitize_hex_color. The output of `var_dump($wp_customize->get_setting("background_color")->sanitize_callback);` is `string(19) "slug_sanitize_color"` so I guess it should work. If more code is needed I can provide it.
My question:
What do I have to do to make Wordpress use my sanitization function for a preexisting control instead of the one Wordpress ships with?
Addition: It all happens inside a function hooked to `customize_register`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
If you want to change the sanitize_callback, sanitize_js_callback or validate_callback you have to manually unregister the old callback function (`remove_filter("customize_sanitize_{$settingid}",$wp_customize->get_setting($settingid)->sanitize_callback);`), then change the value for the object (`$wp_customize->get_setting($settingid)->sanitize_callback = "my_custom_filter_function";`) and finally register the new filter function (`add_filter("customize_sanitize_{$settingid}",my_custom_filter_function,10,2);`).